# Optimize jquery scroll and add / remove class

Tags: jquery

My question is if I'm doing this right. I have a scroll event and add class and remove classes for different elements. As you can see the code is a bit big. Is this method ok or is there a more efficient one?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $("nav ul li").addClass("list-mini");
            $("nav").addClass("nav-mini");
            $("nav ul li a").addClass("nav-recolor");
            $("nav img").removeClass("zoomOutLeft");
            $("nav img").addClass("zoomInUp");
            $("nav img").addClass("logo-mini-active");
            $("nav ul").addClass("margin-transition");
            $("ul").addClass("ul-active");      
            $("nav ul li a span").addClass("text-removed");
            $("nav ul li a").addClass("nav-font");
            $("nav ul li a span").addClass("transition-02s");
            $(".fa-shopping-cart").addClass("fa-shopping-cart-mini");
            $(".fa-globe").addClass("fa-globe-mini");
            $(".fa-info").addClass("fa-info-mini");
            $(".fa-circle-o-notch").addClass("fa-circle-o-notch-mini");
            $(".fa-envelope-o").addClass("fa-envelope-o-mini");
        } else {
            $("*").removeClass("margin-transition, list-mini, nav-mini, nav-recolor, nav-recolor, zoomInUp, zoomOutLeft, ul-active, text-removed, nav-font, transition-02s, fa-shopping-cart-mini, fa-globe-mini, fa-info-mini, fa-circle-o-notch-mini, fa-envelope-o-mini");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, it doesn’t _look_ very nice to begin with … but since you did not comment your code one bit, I’m not going to engage with it any further. And anyway, such a question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CBroe I wanted to post a jsfiddle but I would have to paste every script, html and css which would be an incredible amount of work. Thanks for the link

Comment: Well for starters, in those places where you call `addClass` on the same selection multiple times, you should use `addClass("class1 class2")` instead. Further you should use method chaining, instead of executing the same selectors over and over again. And maybe even cache your selected objects (especially in cases where code might get executed a _lot_ of times, such as in a scroll handler). And whether or not manipulating the classes of such a lot of elements is even necessary, is at least disputable as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711004/how-to-style-focused-and-visited-anchors-when-scrolling-with-css-jquery

Comment: @CBroe im thinking of doing things like forexample $("nav").css({height: '100px'}); instead of adding a class that holds the height value. Which is more effective?  As you can see the problem is every class is unique. No children. If there are siblings then each sibling gets a unique class. Everything is unique. The only thing I can think of is a way to optimize the removal of all those classes within the nav element. Is there a way to target classes globaly? like (".class")?

Comment: @Mottie thanks again. I finally understood how to handle siblings and children when working on menus. Especially the Index is very useful. Just looked at the other question. It is different to mine.

Comment: @CBroe I was trying something but didnt work  $("nav").children().removeClass("margin-transition, list-mini, nav-mini, nav-mini, nav-recolor, zoomInUp");

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: I think it's similar to what you want... check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2zQE/)

Comment: @Mottie the difference is that I have so many unique classes that are given unique addClass. Everythings unique there. I cant even do addClass("class1 class2"). No shorthand method works. The only thing I can think of is of targeting all classes when removing the classes within the else statement.

Comment: I will update my code

Comment: If you were to make more sensible use of _combinators_ in your CSS selectors to begin with, then you could probably reduce all the JS code to simply switching out the class of the top-most `nav` element …

Comment: @CBroe updated code, its shorter now but damn, now it doesnt work. What do you say about it?

Comment: @CBroe you mean like (class 1, class2, class3) right? Thats technically not possible due to some crazy changes taking place

Comment: You should pass the name of classes without comma `,` to `removeClass` method: `$("*").removeClass("a b c d")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better approach would be to stop using a *sh*tload* of classes on *countless* child elements of the navigation – and instead make **intelligent** use of the possibilities CSS offers.

So instead of adding `zoomInUp` to the images, `nav-font` to the links, and so on and so on and so on … simply write your CSS in such a way to begin with, that changing *only* the class of the `nav` parent element changes the formatting of *all* its children where necessary:

```
nav img { /* formatting to apply on images in normal mode */ }
nav.mini img { /* formatting to apply on images in “mini” mode */ }
nav ul li a { /* formatting to apply on links in normal mode */ }
nav.mini ul li a { /* formatting to apply on links in “mini” mode */ }
/* and so on */
```

Then the **only** thing you have to do in your JavaScript, is toggle the class `mini` on the `nav` element – and all children will be affected by either the rules that start with `nav.mini` (when the class is set), or by those that start with just `nav` (when it is not set) *automatically*.

(And if not all elements that need to be affected are children of the `nav` element – not sure, because you are also selecting things such as `.fa-shopping-cart` in your code – then simply don’t apply this technique at `nav` level, but on a higher common parent element.)